# I'm working on enumerations, and I'm getting errors

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GrocerySorter {
   public enum GroceryItem {GR_APPLES, GR_BANANAS, GR_JUICE, GR_WATER};
      public static void main (String [] args) {

      GroceryItem userItem = GroceryItem.GR_APPLES;

         if (userItem == GroceryItem.GR_APPLES) {
            System.out.println("Fruit");
            }
         else if (userItem == GroceryItem.GR_BANANAS) {
            System.out.println("Fruit");
            }
         else if (userItem == GroceryItem.GR_JUICE) {
            System.out.println("Drink");
            }
         else if (userItem == GroceryItem.GR_WATER) {
            System.out.println("Drink");
            } 
         else
            System.out.println("Drink");
            }
      return;
   }
}
```

I'm getting error messages for lines 24 and 26 (The last and second to last ones).

GrocerySorter.java:24: illegal start of type 
return; 
^

GrocerySorter.java:26: class, interface, or enum expected 
}

Comment: You forgot the `{` after the final `else`. So the next `}` is actually closing the method.

Comment: as extra recommendation, you can use switch for this case, it will make the code cleaner and, hopefully, will prevent such mistakes.

Comment: `return;` statement is of no use. Remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing  { after the final else.

Moreover, I advise you to use `switch` instead of `if else`.

```
 switch (userItem) {
      case GR_APPLES:
        System.out.println("Fruit");
        break;
      case GR_BANANAS:
        System.out.println("Fruit");
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you guys, I appreciate it. Switch will work better, I'll keep that in mind next time!